# Console.log is printing unrequested strings

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have this code

```
    function printCompanyAccount(){
        var tempCompanyAccount = companyAccount();
        tempCompanyAccount.printAP();
    }

    var companyAccount = function() {
    var account = {
        printAR: function() {
            //Some logic
            //...
            //Here is when it's acting up.
            console.log("Print account receivable object");
            this.printAP();
        },
        printAP: function() {
            //Business logic
            //...
            console.log("Print account payable object")
        }
    };
    return account;
}
```

when I call tempCompanyAccount.printAP() on printCompanyAccount() it displays

> Print account receivable object
>   Print account payable object

and my belief is it should only print Print account payable object, is it a bad idea to use console.log() since is being used in multiple parts of my code? is it  a better practice for this?

Comment: What is this `this.printAP;` doing there? Is that a `this.printAP()` actually (which would totally explain the observed behaviour)?

Comment: can you show the console output?

Comment: 1. You have a typo in `funtion`, 2. Cannot reproduce with the provided code, but I suspect you are calling the other method in the omitted code.

Comment: I edited the code, now it is running, the out is still this : Print account receivable object Print account payable object in different lines.

Answer (score 1):

It works correctly, if you do not make any typos. See the snippet:

```js
function printCompanyAccount(){
    var tempCompanyAccount = companyAccount();
    tempCompanyAccount.printAP();
}

var companyAccount = function() {
    var account = {
        printAR: function() {
            console.log("Print account receivable object");
            document.body.innerHTML += "Print account receivable object";
        },
        printAP: function() {
            console.log("Print account payable object");
            document.body.innerHTML += "Print account payable object";
        }
    };
    return account;
}

printCompanyAccount();
```

Comment: At least use `+=` instead of `=` when you're abusing `innerHTML` for logging.

Comment: Thanks, i just forgot it. Edited the answer with it.